# Dynamically populate dynamically created select list

Tags: javascript, ajax, dynamic

I'm having a bit of difficulty here; I am using js to dynamically create select boxes, but I need Ajax to fill them with options.  So far, my code is returning undefined, and I frankly don't know what to do here.  My php returns the info fine, but the js isn't parsing it.  Another set of eyes, or another brain full of knowledge would be appreciated here;

```js
function getSkilllist(group) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            return xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","skl_lst_gen2.php?group=" + group + "&t=" + Math.random(),true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function addInput(divName,group) {
var skillst = getSkilllist(group);
var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
newdiv.innerHTML = '<select name="ski[]">' + skillst + '</select> .....
```

The rest of the function is fine, but the var skillst is returning undefined as stated, and I can't figure out why.  I assume it has something to do with strings, but I can't figure out what needs to be done.

Comment: Remember that (normally) Ajax requests are *asynchronous*, so after the `xmlhttp.send()` your other code continues executing without waiting for a response and then the response from the Ajax request is processed later. So your `getSkilllist` function doesn't return anything at all, `skillst` will be undefined, but your other code continues and the `div` is created, etc. When the Ajax response comes in the anonymous function you defined for `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` will execute, so that's where you need to create the `div` as per the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function does not return anything, which is why it isn't working. Try this:

```
function getSkilllist(group) {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
       var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
       newdiv.innerHTML = '<select name="ski[]">' + xmlhttp.responseText + '</select> .....

       //place in DOM here
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","skl_lst_gen2.php?group=" + group + "&t=" + Math.random(),true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

function addInput(divName,group) {
getSkilllist(group);
```