# Drop down list doesn't change in IE

Tags: javascript, mysql, html

This is the url of my page :   http://www.animalswecare.com/Ads/postad.php
There are two fields category and sub category , when category is selected , sub category changes respectively , it is working fine in google chrome , but it has problem with IE, in IE subcategory does not change when category is selected.

Comment: I think this answer will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380304/dynamically-populate-dynamically-created-select-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving id "txtHint" to the select element which is wrong, assign this id to its parent element i.e; TD like

```
<td id="txtHint"><select name="sub_category"></select></td>
```

Answer (score 2):

I encourage you to use jQuery for things like that because they make sure it will work accross almost every browser. Its very easy.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I second that, jQuery or other frameworks are crossbrowser, have a look at them.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot set innerHTML for a select.

instead, you create a `<div id="txtHintWrapper"></div>`

when you do the innerHTML update, include `<select></select>` there

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276228

Answer (score 0):

There's a javascript error in this line:

```
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

It's a known [bug](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2010/06/bug-391-ie-is-strict-in-setting.html).Take a look at this MSDN bug report for a workaround: [BUG: Internet Explorer Fails to Set the innerHTML Property of the Select Object](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276228).

This question talks about it too, and might also be useful: [Javascript - innerHTML not working with HTML select menus](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2738254/851811).

But seeing that the Ajax Request returns the whole `<select>` tag, you should be replacing the parent `<td>`'s `innerHTML`, not the `<select>`'s, as @dev just [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832823/drop-down-list-doesnt-change-in-ie/7832992#7832992).